# Elastic search match_pharse query is not working properly

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to search the below document using `match_phrase` query in kibana but am not getting the response.

Please find the document below which is availabe in elastic search

```
    {  
       "took":7,
       "timed_out":false,
       "_shards":{  
          "total":5,
          "successful":5,
          "skipped":0,
          "failed":0
       },
       "hits":{  
          "total":2910,
          "max_score":1.0,
          "hits":[  
             {  
                "_index":"documents",
                "_type":"doc",
                "_id":"DmLD22MBFTg0XFZppYt8",
                "_score":1.0,
                "_source":{  
                   "doct_country":"DE",
                   "filename":"series_Accessories_v1_de-DE.pdf",


             }

          ]
       }
    }
```

Please find the query which am using to search this above document.

```
GET documents/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "message" : "Accessories_v1_de-DE.pdf"
        }
    }
}
```

For the above query am getting this response :

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.  Presumably in your query you mean to use the `filename` field rather than `message` which is not present in you example document:

```
GET documents/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "filename" : "Accessories_v1_de-DE.pdf"
        }
    }
}
```

Second, you need Elasticsearch to know that the `filename` field should be indexed with `_` treated as a split.  This does not happen by default.  One way to do this is to define your mapping as follows:

```
PUT /documents
{
    "mappings" : {
        "document" : {
            "properties" : {
                "filename" : { "type" : "text", "analyzer": "simple" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The simple analyzer will split on any non-letter, so `_` and numbers will be treated as splits. Depending on your application, you may need finer grained control over tokenization.  See the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html).

Comment: Actually am inserting documents from Oracle database into elasticsearch using Logstash JDBC input plugin., so how i can do  this mappings...?

Comment: You need to apply the mapping directly to your target Elasticsearch cluster.  JDBC is just the input.  You can see a more complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454584/setting-elasticsearch-analyzer-for-new-fields-in-logstash

Comment: is that one time settings via kibana.. for specific index?